# Temporary NSQ Channels

Tags: nsq

I have nodes that need to connect to NSQ, they need to get all the messages for that topic. To do this, they each create a channel. I am wondering if there is a way for nsqd to clean them up after the consumers have been disconnected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSQ allows for "ephemeral channels", from the [docs](http://nsq.io/overview/design.html):

> Note, a topic/channel whose name ends in the string #ephemeral will not be buffered to disk and will instead drop messages after passing the mem-queue-size. This enables consumers which do not need message guarantees to subscribe to a channel. These ephemeral channels will also disappear after its last client disconnects.